# How is the default max Java heap size determined?

Tags: java, heap-memory

If I omit the `-Xmxn` option from the Java command line then a default value will be used. According to [Java documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> "the default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration"

What system configuration settings influence the default value?

Comment: system configuration means: a) client jvm vs server jvm b) 32bit vs 64bit.                          Links: 1) updation from J2SE5.0 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html   2) brief answer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html  3) detailed answer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#default_heap_size  4) client vs server: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/jvm-options-client-vs-server.html

Comment: its tough to understand from the above links. So summarizing them here: Maximum heap size for Client jvm is 256mb (there is an exception, read from links above). Maximun heap size for Server jvm of 32bit is 1gb and of 64 bit is 32gb (again there are exceptions here too. Kindly read that from the links). So its 256mb or 1gb or 32gb

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036202/32453

Answer (score 644):

On Windows, you can use the following command to find out the defaults on the system where your applications runs.

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr HeapSize
```

Look for the options `MaxHeapSize` (for `-Xmx`) and `InitialHeapSize` for `-Xms`.

On a Unix/Linux system, you can do

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
```

I believe the resulting output is in bytes.

Comment: I was hoping for a nice option like this, but it didn't work for me using IBM's Java 6 VM.

Comment: Great! Can I play with all these default options? What's the corresponding ENV variable for each?

Comment: In my case on Linux, `InitialHeapSize = 262803264` and `MaxHeapSize = 4206886912` which is about **256 MB** and **4 GB** if I'm not mistaken. Does this mean that every JVM starts as if it was launched with `-Xms256m -Xmx4g` options?

Comment: On a Windows system: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /R /C:"HeapSize"`

Comment: Kind of a partial answer only to the original question as asked, but very very helpful! I think the `-version` part is not necessary though.

Comment: So... what does 0 mean? :)

Comment: @matanster On my Linux `-version` suppresses the long "usage" text on `stderr`.

Comment: i get 'java not recognized as internal command' error. at what folder in the command line do you have to be at for this to work.

Comment: The Unix version does indeed work on macOS 10.14 on 64-bit Intel Mac mini with 32-gigs of memory running Java 15 from AdoptOpenJDK. Shows `MaxHeapSize = 8589934592` and `MinHeapSize = 8388608`.

Comment: `grep HeapSize | numfmt --to=iec --field=4` will show human-readable sizes

Answer (score 129):

For Java SE 5: According to [Garbage Collector Ergonomics [Oracle]](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html):

> **initial heap size:**
>
> Larger of 1/64th of the machine's physical memory on the machine or some
>   reasonable minimum. Before J2SE 5.0,
>   the default initial heap size was a
>   reasonable minimum, which varies by
>   platform. You can override this
>   default using the -Xms command-line
>   option.
>
> **maximum heap size:**
>
> Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB. Before J2SE 5.0, the
>   default maximum heap size was 64MB.
>   You can override this default using
>   the -Xmx command-line option.

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out by Tom Anderson in his comment, the above is for server-class machines. From [Ergonomics in the 5.0 JavaTM Virtual Machine](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/ergo5.html):

> In the J2SE platform version 5.0 a
>   class of machine referred to as a
>   server-class machine has been defined
>   as a machine with
>
> - 2 or more physical processors
> - 2 or more Gbytes of physical memory
>
> with the exception of 32 bit platforms
>   running a version of the Windows
>   operating system. On all other
>   platforms the default values are the
>   same as the default values for version
>   1.4.2.
>
> In the J2SE platform version 1.4.2 by
>   default the following selections were
>   made
>
> - initial heap size of 4 Mbyte
> - maximum heap size of 64 Mbyte

Comment: Caveat: that's for server-class machines, not client-class. You need to read that document in conjunction with http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/ergo5.html which defines those terms and what happens to client-class machines. dogbane, might i humbly suggest you edit your answer to quote the relevant passages?

Comment: That is a ridiculously low default in 2012. Very few serious applications will fit inside 64 megabytes.

Comment: See Ernesto's Oct 30, 2012 answer for client machines after Java 6 update 18.

Comment: Also keep in mind that it says: "The boundaries and fractions given for the heap size are correct for J2SE 5.0. They are likely to be different in subsequent releases as computers get more powerful."

Comment: By the way, this algo is only for Parallel Garbage Collector.

Answer (score 78):

Java 8 takes more than *1/64th* of your physical memory for your *Xmssize* (Minimum HeapSize) and less than *1/4th* of your physical memory for your *-Xmxsize* (Maximum HeapSize).

You can check the **default Java heap size** by:

In **Windows**:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"
```

In **Linux**:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
```

> What system configuration settings influence the default value?

The machine's **physical memory & Java version.**

Comment: isn't it 1/64 instead of 1/6?

Comment: Yeah Xmssize (Minimum HeapSize / InitialHeapSize) is more than 1/64th of your physical memory & Xmxsize (Maximum HeapSize / MaxHeapSize) is less than 1/4th of your physical memory . (For-ex for my mac , having 16GB ram , I am getting                                                                                                                                     uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 268435456                           {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 4294967296                          {product} , i,e Xms is 268 MB & Xmx is 4.29 GB

Comment: The values are in Bytes, if you want MB divide by 1024*1024

Comment: This has really saved me lot of time, thanks a lot :)

Comment: is any way to set heap size over then 1/4th physical memory?

Answer (score 43):

This is changed in [Java 6 update 18](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u18-142093.html).

Assuming that we have more than *1 GB* of physical memory (quite common these days), it's always 1/4th of your physical memory for the server vm.

Comment: Incorrect, the linked page says `greater than or equal to 1 gigabyte of physical memory results in a maximum heap size of 256 megabytes`

Comment: I just checked on a linux machine with 5gb physical memory. Default max heap shows as 1.5gb

Comment: @PaoloFulgoni no, another practical example I observe right now: 129 Gbytes of physical memory results in 32 Gbyte of max heap size

Comment: For more info on why this is the case see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13310792/32453 See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036202/32453

Comment: The section quoted by @PaoloFulgoni refers to a `client` VM. The examples by @ernesto and @Kirill are likely a server VM which is the default configuration when you're using the JDK VM as opposed to JRE.

Answer (score 37):

Finally!

As of Java 8u191 you now have the options:

```
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage
-XX:MinRAMPercentage
```

that can be used to size the heap as a percentage of the usable physical RAM. (which is same as the RAM installed less what the kernel uses).

See [Release Notes for Java8 u191](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u191-relnotes-5032181.html) for more information. Note that the options are mentioned under a Docker heading but in fact they apply whether you are in Docker environment or in a traditional environment.

The default value for `MaxRAMPercentage` is 25%. This is extremely conservative.

My own rule: If your host is more or less dedicated to running the given java application, then you can without problems increase dramatically. If you are on Linux,  only running standard daemons and have installed RAM from somewhere around 1 Gb and up then I wouldn't hesitate to use 75% for the JVM's heap. Again, remember that this is 75% of the RAM *available*, not the RAM *installed*. What is left is the other user land processes that may be running on the host and the other types of memory that the JVM needs (eg for stack). All together, this will typically fit nicely in the 25% that is left. Obviously, with even more installed RAM the 75% is a safer and safer bet. (I wish the JDK folks had implemented an option where you could specify a ladder)

Setting the `MaxRAMPercentage` option look like this:

```
java -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0  ....
```

Note that these percentage values are of 'double' type and therefore you **must** specify them with a decimal dot. You get a somewhat odd error if you use "75" instead of "75.0".

Comment: It seems that `MinRAMPercentage` parameter, unlike its name, allows setting the maximum heap size for a JVM running *with a small amount of memory* (less than around 250MB), and `MaxRAMPercentage` allows setting the maximum heap size for a JVM running *with a large amount of memory* (greater than around 250 MB). So the default values depend on the amount of RAM. The other value is ignored. You can get the default values with `docker run --rm openjdk:8 java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -E "RAMPercentage"`. `MaxRAMPercentage = 25.0` and `MinRAMPercentage = 50%` on my laptop.

Comment: these parameter is not working in ' traditional environment',  i use the jdk8u333

Comment: @sendreams: Did you remember to use decimal point when specifying the value?

Comment: @peterh yes, i really use, but use visualvm connect the instance, the max heap size is always 16GB

Comment: @peterh i have made a mistake, it can working now. tks

Answer (score 19):

The `Xms` and `Xmx` are flag of Java virtual machine (JVM):

- `Xms`: `initial and minimum` JVM `heap size`

  - `Format`: `-Xms<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]`
  - `Default Size`:

    - `-server` mode: 25% of free physical memory, >=8MB and <= 64MB
    - `-client mode`: 25% of free physical memory, >=8MB and <= 16MB
  - `Typical Size`:

    - `-Xms128M`
    - `-Xms256M`
    - `-Xms512M`
  - `Function`/`Effect`:

    - -> JVM start with allocate `Xms` size memory
- `Xmx`: `maximum` JVM `heap size`

  - `Format`: `-Xmx<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]`
  - `Default Size`:

    - `<= R27.2`

      - `Windows`: `75%` of total physical memory up to `1GB`
      - `Linux/Solaris`: `50%` of available physical memory up to `1GB`
    - `>= R27.3`

      - `Windows X64`: `75%` of total physical memory up to `2GB`
      - `Linux/Solaris X64`: `50%` of available physical memory up to `2GB`
      - `Windows x86`: `75%` of total physical memory up to `1GB`
      - `Linux/Solaris X86`: `50%` of available physical memory up to `1GB`
  - `Typical Size`:

    - `-Xmx1g`
    - `-Xmx2084M`
    - `-Xmx4g`
    - `-Xmx6g`
    - `-Xmx8g`
  - `Function`/`Effect`:

    - -> JVM allow use maxium of `Xmx` size memory

      - when exceed `Xmx`, will `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

        - How to fix `OutOfMemoryError` ?

          - exceed `Xmx` value

            - eg: from `-Xmx4g` to `-Xmx8g`

#### More detail

see  official doc: [-X Command-line Options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html)

Comment: Isn't that for the JRockit JVM?  (as opposed to Oracle's Hotspot JVM)

Answer (score 16):

Ernesto is right.  According to the link he posted [1]:

> Updated Client JVM heap configuration
>
> In the Client JVM...
>
> - The default maximum heap size is half of the physical memory up to a physical memory size of 192 megabytes and otherwise one fourth of the physical memory up to a physical memory size of 1 gigabyte.
>
>   For example, if your machine has 128 megabytes of physical memory, then the maximum heap size is 64 megabytes, and greater than or equal to 1 gigabyte of physical memory results in a maximum heap size of 256 megabytes.
> - The maximum heap size is not actually used by the JVM unless your program creates enough objects to require it. A much smaller amount, termed the initial heap size, is allocated during JVM initialization. ...
> - ...
> - Server JVM heap configuration ergonomics are now the same as the Client, except that **the default maximum heap size for 32-bit JVMs is 1 gigabyte**, corresponding to a physical memory size of 4 gigabytes, and **for 64-bit JVMs is 32 gigabytes**, corresponding to a physical memory size of 128 gigabytes.

[1] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u18-142093.html

Answer (score 10):

For the IBM JVM, the command is the following:

```
java -verbose:sizes -version
```

For more information about the IBM SDK for Java 8: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.80.doc/diag/appendixes/defaults.html?lang=en

Comment: The link seems to be (effectively) broken.

Comment: @PeterMortensen just checked - link is fine

Comment: @NikHandyman Broken now: `We're sorry!
Content not found`

Answer (score 8):

> default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration

Have a look at the documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#default_heap_size)

> Default Heap Size
>
> Unless the initial and maximum heap sizes are specified on the command line, they are calculated based on the amount of memory on the machine.

1. Client JVM Default Initial and Maximum Heap Sizes:

   The default maximum heap size is *half of the physical memory up to a physical memory size of 192 megabytes (MB)* and otherwise *one fourth of the physical memory up to a physical memory size of 1 gigabyte (GB)*.
2. Server JVM Default Initial and Maximum Heap Sizes:

   On 32-bit JVMs, *the default maximum heap size can be up to 1 GB if there is 4 GB or more of physical memory*. *On 64-bit JVMs, the default maximum heap size can be up to 32 GB if there is 128 GB or more of physical memory*

> What system configuration settings influence the default value?

You can specify the initial and maximum heap sizes using the flags ***-Xms*** (initial heap size) and ***-Xmx*** (maximum heap size). If you know how much heap your application needs to work well, you can set ***-Xms*** and ***-Xmx*** to the same value

Answer (score 6):

A number of parameters affect generation size. The following diagram illustrates the difference between committed space and virtual space in the heap. At initialization of the virtual machine, the entire space for the heap is reserved. The size of the space reserved can be specified with the `-Xmx` option. If the value of the `-Xms` parameter is smaller than the value of the `-Xmx` parameter, not all of the space that is reserved is immediately committed to the virtual machine. The uncommitted space is labeled "virtual" in this figure. The different parts of the heap (permanent generation, tenured generation and young generation) can grow to the limit of the virtual space as needed.

[image]

By default, the virtual machine grows or shrinks the heap at each collection to try to keep the proportion of free space to live objects at each collection within a specific range. This target range is set as a percentage by the parameters -`XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=<minimum>` and `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=<maximum>`, and the total size is bounded below by `-Xms<min>` and above by `-Xmx<max>`.

Parameter           Default Value

MinHeapFreeRatio    40

MaxHeapFreeRatio    70

-Xms    3670k

-Xmx    64m

Default values of heap size parameters on 64-bit systems have been scaled up by approximately 30%. This increase is meant to compensate for the larger size of objects on a 64-bit system.

With these parameters, if the percent of free space in a generation falls below 40%, the generation will be expanded to maintain 40% free space, up to the maximum allowed size of the generation. Similarly, if the free space exceeds 70%, the generation will be contracted so that only 70% of the space is free, subject to the minimum size of the generation.

Large server applications often experience two problems with these defaults. One is slow startup, because the initial heap is small and must be resized over many major collections. A more pressing problem is that the default maximum heap size is unreasonably small for most server applications. The rules of thumb for server applications are:

- Unless you have problems with pauses, try granting as much memory as
  possible to the virtual machine. The default size (64MB) is often too
  small.
- Setting -Xms and -Xmx to the same value increases predictability by
  removing the most important sizing decision from the virtual machine.
  However, the virtual machine is then unable to compensate if you make
  a poor choice.
- In general, increase the memory as you increase the number of
  processors, since allocation can be parallelized.

  There is the [full article](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html)