# What's my JVM Heap Size?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, heap-size

How do I determine the JVM heap size default values??

Note that I'm not interested in setting or modifying its initial, minimum, or maximum size before/while running my application. I just want to know what it is on a given machine if I do nothing!

Comment: 256 MB is default Heap size. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/xdoo/Modifying+the+JVM+heap+size

Comment: Thanks Divyesh, but the more I read, the more I find different values that are true only under certain conditions. I'm trying to ask the JVM or the System directly..

Comment: You may want to read this previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined

Comment: The Java 7 docs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

Comment: Yes its change under cretain condition ...............

Comment: If you care what it is you should set it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```

Comment: 61800448! why don't I like this number??

Comment: The heap will dynamically grow/shrink as you use more/less memory. I think the JVM itself has a bunch of overhead as well.