# OutOfMemory: Java heap space

Tags: java, exception, heap-memory

I am running the same java program on a windows and on a linux machine.
on windows i get OutOfMemory if i do not add -Xmx option (set to 512).
while on linux the program runs successfully even without -Xmx option.

My guess is its because windows and linux handles memory differently.
Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the default java heap size determined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)

Comment: Is the configuration of both Windows and Unix machine same? (Processor, Memory, 32 bit or 64 bit)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default maximum memory is 1/4 up to 1 GB of your main memory on server class machines. e.g. Linux.  Windows 32-bit is considered a client class machine and the default maximum is 64 MB.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf