# What does Java start the heap at if I do not specify a -Xms?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, jvm-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the default java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)

Im curious what happens if I do not specify a `-Xms` for initial JVM heap size with Java?

Currently I have `-Xms256m and -Xmx512m` but this gives me an error on my server :

```
Failed to create JVM, return code is:-1
```

I believe the JVM is having trouble getting 256MB of contiguous memory with a 256m starting point.  Prior to today we only had a `-Xmx256m` setting but had some processes that were running out of memory.

Can the JVM function if I remove the `-Xms` setting and just leave the `-Xmx512m`'?  What does the heap start with?

**How does it acquire contiguous memory if no starting heap is declared?**

Comment: @TedHopp - But if I specify the max, how does the system ensure it gets contiguous memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question. Please look at Ted Hopp's comment.   **[How is the default java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)**

Secondly you don't need to specify and minimum and a maximum heap size. You are also inputting them incorrectly.

It should be `-Xms256m -Xmx512m`

Initial heap size will be `4Mbyte` with a **max** heap of `64Mbyte` on client class machines.

Comment: But if I specify the max, how does the system ensure it gets contiguous memory if I allow the system to default with the min?

Comment: Is there a reason you need a contiguous memory region?

Comment: The JVM requires it.  We are still using Oracle/Sun JDK (1.5 I believe) so it requires contiguous memory.  Our documentation states `But some times XML Publisher kernel will not start if JVM could not get contiguous block of memory.`

Comment: I see. Well have you tried without setting the initial heap size? It should (or at least I would hope it should) do some talking with the OS to request the address space as the requirement grows. If you are on a machine with limited memory, the only option would be to go 64bit java as getting contiguous memory region is easier in that address space.

Comment: I can try that, Im searching for info on how the JVM does that though before I do. JRockit JVM doesnt require contiguous memory too, but I do not want to swap the JVMs on all my servers if I can help it now.  Appreciate the input

Answer (score 2):

**Default Initial size:**

`Larger of 1/64th of the System's physical memory on the machine or some reasonable minimum.` `Before J2SE 5.0, the default initial heap size was a reasonable minimum, which varies by` `platform.`

Comment: But if I specify the max, how does the system ensure it gets contiguous memory?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur It doesn't have to. That's what virtual memory is for, among other things.

Comment: @EJP - But my kernel does required it for some odd reason.  `But some times XML Publisher kernel will not start if JVM could not get contiguous block of memory.`  Maybe my kernel requests it from the JVM and the JVM itself doesnt care.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur What kernel are you referring to? Some application? Kernels don't request things from the JVM: it's the other way around. I think you've misunderstood something here. The last non-virtual-memory system I worked on was in 1993.

Comment: @EJP - This is a BI Publisher kernel for an Oracle product we have on a large enterprise system.  Essentially a mail merge process that takes XML values and merges them with a report template to produce reports/pdfs/excel/etc...  Im guessing that this process needs contiguous memory to interact with the JVM and not the JVM itself at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `=`:

```
-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

I think that the default has historically 2 MB, but it depends on your version of Java and your platform.  I'll try to dig up the docs.

Comment: You're right, we did not typo in my post, Ill fix it.