# What is the default max heap size (-Xmx) in Java 8?

Tags: java, memory

In [the oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) I found:

> -Xmx*size* Specifies the maximum size (in bytes) of the memory allocation pool in bytes ... The default
> value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration.

What does *system configuration* mean?

Comment: It means that if your system has 16 GB of RAM, the size will be bigger than if it has 512 MB.

Comment: Thanks, how much bigger?

Comment: Look for "maximum heap size" [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

Comment: >>Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB. Thanks, @alfasin.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/ergo5-140223.html

Comment: @Vitaly The 1Gb limit seems don't hold for `-Xmx`, at least in Java 8, because on my linux 64bit system, with total memory as 6Gb, I have a jvm has -Xmx = 1.5Gb, by default.

Comment: @Vitaly kindly note that your answer is for Java SE5. From SE8, maximum heap size is 256mb by default for client jvm.

Comment: @Eric Wang you might have used server jvm instead of client jvm. Server jvm can have 1gb or 32 gb max heap size by default depending on the ram

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the default max Java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-max-java-heap-size-determined)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

It varies on implementation and version, but usually it depends on the VM used (e.g. client or server, see `-client` and `-server` parameters) and on your system memory.

Often for `client` the default value is 1/4th of your physical memory or 1GB (whichever is smaller).

Also Java configuration options (command line parameters) can be "outsourced" to environment variables including the `-Xmx`, which can change the default (meaning specify a new default). Specifically the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable is checked by all Java tools and used if exists (more details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/envvars.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions)).

You can run the following command to see default values:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version
```

It gives you a loooong list, `-Xmx` is in `MaxHeapSize`, `-Xms` is in `InitialHeapSize`. Filter your output (e.g. `|grep` on linux) or save it in a file so you can search in it.

Comment: As a small addition, you can run `java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags` to print out the heap sizes (and other information) chosen by the JVM based on current system information

Comment: @CristianVat Yes, but the parameter is `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`, the one you suggested does not work for me. Adding it to the answer.

Comment: Right, sorry `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` is the best option since it should show all information after everything has been taken into account (including manual options and ergonomics). Although `-XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags` seems to work on my JVM (might depend on exact version)

Comment: For large boxes, this "1/4th RAM" rule of thumb definitely does not hold.  On a 4-socket, 64gb per socket server (i.e. 256gb RAM), Xmx defaults to ~32gb.  32gb may be related to CompressedOops' limitations being at around this point, too.

Comment: This only print heap size related lines: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize`

Comment: Is there a way to change the 1/4th ratio value itself instead of the Xmx value? It would help in a containerised scenario with `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` flag on.

Comment: @icza I believe 1/4th corresponds to client jvm and 1gb corresponds to server jvm of 4gb/more of physical memory. And 32gb for server jvm of 128gb/more physical memory. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @VyshnavRameshThrissur It may be. Do you have sources (link) to confirm?

Comment: @icza i have posted it as an answer below. Kindly have a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036202/5649620

Comment: you also can use `jinfo <pid_of_java>` to get info from running process.

Comment: Something is not quite right here. I just saw a `client` VM (which is the default if you install JRE instead of JDK). The default `MapHeapSize` is 256MB - on a Windows 16GB RAM machine. I think the answer of @VyshnavRameshThrissur is more accurate in this regard.

Answer (score 51):

Like you have mentioned, The default `-Xmxsize` (Maximum HeapSize) depends on your system configuration.

**Java8 `client` takes Larger of 1/64th of your physical memory for your `Xmssize` (Minimum HeapSize) and Smaller of 1/4th of your physical memory for your `-Xmxsize` (Maximum HeapSize).**

Which means if you have a physical memory of 8GB RAM, you will have `Xmssize` as Larger of 8*(1/64) and Smaller of `-Xmxsize`as 8*(1/4).

**You can Check your default HeapSize with**

In **Windows**:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"
```

In **Linux**:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
```

These default values can also be overrided to your desired amount.

Comment: Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#default_heap_size

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html as per this link, default for minimum/initial is 1/64 not 1/6. "Larger of 1/64th of the machine's physical memory on the machine or some reasonable minimum"

Answer (score 16):

Surprisingly this question doesn't have a definitive documented answer.  Perhaps another data point would provide value to others looking for an answer.  On my systems running CentOS (6.8,7.3) and Java 8 (build 1.8.0_60-b27, 64-Bit Server):

default memory is 1/4 of physical memory, not limited by 1GB.

Also, `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` prints to STDERR so command to determine current default memory presented by others above should be tweaked to the following:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2>&1 | grep MaxHeapSize
```

The following is returned on system with 64GB of physical RAM:

```
uintx MaxHeapSize                                  := 16873684992      {product}
```

Comment: In my system with 16 Gb of RAM: 2069889024 = 2 Gb.

Comment: Windows 7 64bit with 8 GB of RAM: 32bit JVMs: 256 MB, 64bit JVMs: 2 GB

Comment: Finally found the documentation for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036202/32453

Answer (score 5):

On my Ubuntu VM, with 1048 MB total RAM, `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize` printed :  `uintx MaxHeapSize := 266338304`, which is approx 266MB and is 1/4th of my total RAM.

Comment: It's looking to me like OpenJDK and Oracle have different characteristics - I see OpenJDK using 1/4 of RAM as -Xmx at all times (never the smaller of 1/4 and 1GB)

Answer (score 5):

As of **8, May, 2019:**

JVM heap size depends on system configuration, meaning:

**a) client jvm vs server jvm**

**b) 32bit vs 64bit**.

**Links:**

1) updation from J2SE5.0: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html
2) brief answer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html
3) detailed answer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#default_heap_size
4) client vs server: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/jvm-options-client-vs-server.html

**Summary:** 
(Its tough to understand from the above links. So summarizing them here)

1) Default maximum heap size for Client jvm is 256mb (there is an exception, read from links above).

2) Default maximum heap size for Server jvm of 32bit is 1gb and of 64 bit is 32gb (again there are exceptions here too. Kindly read that from the links).

So default maximum jvm heap size is: **256mb** or **1gb** or **32gb** depending on VM, above.

Comment: Finally links to real docu that explain what is going on.