# Default JVM Memory

Tags: jvm

Whenever I am starting JVM it is getting started with Xms as 256MB, which is 1/64 of the Memory available and by default this should happen.
But I want to change and start the every JVM with 128MB.
Is there any way to do or I have to manually specify Xms tag while starting JVM.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default Xmxsize in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272923/default-xmxsize-in-java-8)

Answer (score -1):

You can provide the default arguments for every JVM but this way prevent you from changing it later.  The simplest solution is to have startup script which sets your default values for you.

BTW, the default is only 1/64th on 32-bit client JVM for Windows. For all 64-bit versions, the default is 1/4 of main memory.  This is only the maximum heap size, not the amount actually used which could be more or less in total.