# Image in memory consuming much more memory than its file size

Tags: java, image, memory, memory-management

I am using Java (Eclipse) to build a application that works with photos.

So I used this link [Java get available memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807797/java-get-available-memory) to know how much free memory I still have. The issue is that I have this code:

```
Main.printMemory("before image");
url = new File(information.getPath()).toURI().toURL();
image = ImageIO.read(url);
Main.printMemory("after image");
```

And the result is:

> Message: before image 
>  Free memory (bytes): 82554768   
>   Maximum memory (bytes): 129957888   
>  Total memory (bytes):
>   85000192

and

> Message: after image 
>  Free memory (bytes): 42600680  
>  Maximum
>   memory (bytes): 129957888    
>  Total memory (bytes): 85000192

So loading that image takes `82554768 - 42600680  = 39954088 bytes = 38 MB`

The photo size is 3.3 MB

Is it normal to take so much memory??? Why does it consume so much memory? Is there any way I could reduce this, hopefully maintaining the photo quality?

Comment: How big is the image, in pixels?

Comment: 4000 × 3000 and its a JPEG image

Comment: 4000 x 3000 x 3 bytes/pixel = 36000000 bytes. (Images are not stored compressed in memory)

Comment: I just loaded 5 photos, all of around 2-4MB and the free memory

Comment: oscillated 82554872 to 42839376 to 31523760 to 54946760 to 43621704 to  6062136 to 18054976

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *file size* of a compressed and encoded image is a bad indicator for the memory requirements to store an image. Images in main memory are usually uncompressed, because using a compressed encoding would make image operations both more complex and a lot slower.

You have a `4,000 x 3,000` JPEG image. Since the source is JPEG encoded, it might get loaded by `ImageIO` with `TYPE_INT_RGB` meaning every pixel requires `4` bytes (an `int`) of storage space. This means the decoded image will use up to need `4,000 x 3,000 x 4 = 48,000,000` bytes of memory. This number might even be larger when Java gets support for 16bit color depth.

That it only needs ~ 38MB sounds like the image is not fully unpacked (`TYPE_INT_RGB`) but actually represented in some packed encoding (e.g. `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` would need 36 MB) in main memory.

Images are BIG.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, yes. The reason is that most image formats are compressed in some way -- this is true of gif, jpeg and png, for instance -- but BufferedReader is not. That is, it records data for every pixel independently, without trying to compress or consolidate this information. That yields a much bigger memory footprint: width x height x (bytes per pixel). If that last one is 4 bytes, you can see how pictures can get pretty big pretty fast.

There's not much you can do about it if you want to work with the images -- to rotate them, filter then, etc. This is why photo editing tools have always been memory hogs! If you don't need the full resolution, you can downsample the images, using something like [imgscalr](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr) or some other library.