# Get memory used by Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, memory, process, runtime

I'm using java and I want to manage used memory of Process. I used `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();` to run an application. For example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/bangjdev/testapp"); // on Linux
```

Now the problem is: I want to know how much memory this Process used?
I have tried to used freeMemory() but it seems not true, for example:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long bfore = rt.freeMemory();
        try {
            rt.exec("/home/bangjdev/Documents/test");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long after = rt.freeMemory();

        System.out.println("Used " + (bfore - after) + " bytes");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807797/java-get-available-memory/18366283#18366283

Comment: @bang do you want to know memory usage of aunched process or your java process ?

Comment: I exactly want to know memory usage of launched process

Comment: anyone can help me :(