# javac default memoryInitialSize and memoryMaximumSize?

Tags: java, ant, compiler-construction, javac

What are the default values for **javac** parameters **memoryInitialSize** and **memoryMaximumSize**? Does it take these values from an env/os property or setting?

```
<javac 
  srcdir="@{srcdir}" 
  destdir="@{destdir}"
  includeantruntime="@{includeantruntime}"
  debug="@{debug}" 
  deprecation="@{deprecation}" 
  target="@{target}"
  source="@{target}"
  fork="@{fork}" 
  executable="@{executable}"
  memoryInitialSize="@{memoryInitialSize}"
  memoryMaximumSize="@{memoryMaximumSize}">
  <compilerarg compiler="${build.compiler}" line="${build.compiler.args}"/>
  <javac-elements/>
</javac>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined

Comment: Did you have a look [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) says, that ant uses the standard VM memory settings if javac runs externally. As dkatzel points out in his comment, those VM setting are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined).