# java heap space error when converting csv to json but no error with d3.csv()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

- Platform being used: Apache Zeppelin
- Language: scala, javascript

I use d3js to read a csv file of size ~40MB and it works perfectly fine with the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
d3.csv("test.csv", function(data) {
    // data is JSON array. Do something with data;
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

Now, the idea is to avoid d3js, instead, construct the JSONarray in scala and access this variable in javascript code through z.angularBind(). Both of the below code works for smaller files, but gives java heap space error for the CSV file of size 40MB. What I am unable to understand is when d3.csv() can perfectly do the job without any heap space error, why cannot these 2 below code?

**Edited Code 1:** Using scala's

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import org.json._
import scala.io.Source

var br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/root/test.csv"))
var contentLine = br.readLine();
var keys = contentLine.split(",")
contentLine = br.readLine();
var ja = new JSONArray();
while (contentLine != null) {
    var splits = contentLine.split(",")
    var i = 0
    var jo = new JSONObject()
    for(i <- 0 to splits.length-1){
        jo.put(keys(i), splits(i));    
    }
    ja.put(jo);
    contentLine = br.readLine();
}
//z.angularBind("ja",ja.toString()) //ja can be accessed now in javascript (EDITED-10/11/15)
```

**Edited Code 2:**
I thought the heap space issue might go away if I use Apache spark to construct the JSON array like in below code, but this one too gives heap space error:

```
def myf(keys: Array[String], value: String):String = {
    var splits = value.split(",")
    var jo = new JSONObject()
    for(i <- 0 to splits.length-1){            
        jo.put(keys(i), splits(i));
    }
    return(jo.toString())
}

val csv = sc.textFile("/root/test.csv")
val firstrow = csv.first
val header = firstrow.split(",")
val data = csv.filter(x => x != firstrow)

var g = data.map(value => myf(header,value)).collect()
// EDITED BELOW 2 LINES-10/11/15
//var ja= g.mkString("[", ",", "]") 
//z.angularBind("ja",ja) //ja can be accessed now in javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating JSON-objects. They are not native to java/scala and will therefore take up more space in that environment. What does z.angularBind() really do?

Also what is the heap size of your javascript environment (see https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-JavaScript-object-in-browser-memory for chrome) and your java environment (see [How is the default java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)).

**Update**: Removed the original part of the answer where I misunderstood the question

Comment: jvm max heapsize set for the application is 1024m. Even doubling this value is not helping and the javascript heapsize limit is the default 793mb in google chrome. Also, I checked the "about:memory" in chrome and I get these numbers for my tab  +(a)Total Memory=86812k (b)Mapped virtual memory=250308k.  z.angularBind() is [Apache zeppelin's mechanizm](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/displaysystem/angular.html) to share data between different notebooks. i.e. we can share data between scala code written in one notebook/paragraph and javascript code written in another notebook/paragraph

Comment: ... and that data must be shared as org.json objects?

Comment: we can share anything. But I chose to share it as json string. Instead, I could have also created a string variable representing the entire file and share the string variable itself and then in javascript do JSON.parse(string_variable). This doesn't help either.

Comment: ... and you're sure that it won't be able to automatically convert vanilla objects to json on the fly? I see the project (https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-interpreter/pom.xml) includes gson (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson) which suggest that possibillity.

Comment: I am sorry to come back late..... yes, you were very right in mentioning that there is no need for conversion. Thanks for the hint. The scala objects can straight away be accessed inside javascript code. However, the error still persists. I suppose this has got to do something with memory allocated to JVM. For testing purpose, I executed the above codes directly in "apache spark-shell" and it still gives heap space error inspite of allocating sufficient memory(4GB) for [spark.driver.memory](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)