# What can be the maximum preferable size guava cache can use?

Tags: java, caching, guava, google-guava-cache

What can be the maximum preferable size guava cache can use?My system has 8 gb RAM so without degrading the performance of system and other applications how much MB's can i use ? Does Guava cache also use hardDisk storage when RAM storage is not available ?

Comment: No, the Guava cache is strictly on-heap.  It's not going to make much difference how big it is, it's just a fancy hash map.

Answer (score 6):

You can only limit the number of entries in the cache. In Guava there is no way to specify the size limit in megabytes. [EHCache](http://www.ehcache.org/) supports specifying the size limit in megabytes, however, determining the size of a cached entry, is a difficult task and involves some magic, guessing, and, a performance overhead.

> Does Guava cache also use hardDisk storage when RAM storage is not available?

No, it is Java heap only. See [CachesExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) for details.

In practice you start with a reasonable but low cache size, and increase it, while keeping and eye on your heap memory consumption.

Actually the question "How to size a cache?" is not easy to answer, usually there is experience combined with gut feeling involved. To broaden the answer a little and give you more directions:

**Prerequisites**

- Make sure you understand the general concepts of the Java heap and garbage collection
- Know/check the maximum heap size setting of your JVM. See: [How is the default java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)
- Learn how to monitor and interpret the heap consumption and GC activity, e.g. with VisualVM, see: http://visualvm.java.net/monitor_tab.html
- Know how to retrieve and interpret statistics from the cache, especially the hit rate
- Know your data, the estimated size in byte of one entry and the size count of your active data set

**Rules of thumb**

- Aim for a hit rate of 90% and more. If it is less, increase the cache size, or, have an idea why the cache is not very effective. Possible causes: Cache misses because of a low expiry time, lots of sequential scans. Sometimes you can improve your application or fiddle with other parameters then the cache size to optimize your hit rate.
- For a first "best bet" configure your cache size (in entry counts) at least of 10% of your active data set size

Comment: I dont have data to analyse just in your pov If my current ram usage is around 50% then can I use 100 mb data in cache ?

Comment: Of course, 100 MB shouldn't be a problem. However, double check the maximum heap size of your JVM. I'll update my answer.