# How much maximum heap space does a Play Framework App use per default

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, playframework, netty

I am deploying a Play Framework 2.4 Application as a Docker Container on AWS. I have to specify a Hard/Soft Memory Limit for the Container.

I do not know what limit to choose and wanted to set it to the maximum amount of heap space the App might be using.

Researching I only found discussions and instructions on how to change the maximum heap space of a Play App, but I couldn't figure out to what it is set per default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set explicitly then it is defined by JVM.
Usually it is 1/4 of your phisical memory.

You can check for sure using instructions from here:
[How is the default java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)