# Kafka Connect running out of heap space

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jvm, apache-kafka-connect

After starting Kafka Connect (`connect-standalone`), my task fails immediately after starting with:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:343)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:291)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:248)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1013)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:979)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:222)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:140)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

There's a mention of heap space in some Kafka documentation, telling you to try it with "the default" and only modifying it if there are problems, but there are no instructions to modify the heap space.

Comment: The "default size" seems to be [determined at run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined).  It appears to be large enough in my machine (8G).  I still get the OOM error.  Besides, there are all sorts of other exceptions in the connector log, and the server stalls.  Very frustrating.

Comment: From what I found, it's hard-coded to 256M: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L209

Comment: ohhh! thank you.  That explains.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can control the max and initial heap size by setting the `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` environment variable.

The following example sets a starting size of 512 MB and a maximum size of 1 GB:

```
KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1g" connect-standalone connect-worker.properties connect-s3-sink.properties
```

When running a Kafka command such as `connect-standalone`, the `kafka-run-class` script is invoked, which [sets a default heap size of 256 MB](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L233) in the `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` environment variable if it is not already set.

Comment: As of Kafka 1.1.0, the new default for Connect is `-Xmx2g`, and it is set before `kafka-run-class` - https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/cfa6a78c7c2529839d2f3cb1129098f2e552fd72

Comment: Any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: The method in my answer is the same, only the default value changed.

Answer (score 115):

When you have Kafka problems with

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

it doesn't necessarily mean that it's a memory problem. Several Kafka admin tools like `kafka-topics.sh` will mask the true error with this when trying to connect to an SSL PORT. The true (masked) error is `SSL handshake failed` !

See this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4090

The solution is to include a properties file in your command (for `kafka-topics.sh` this would be `--command-config`) and to absolutely include this line:

```
security.protocol=SSL
```

Comment: for my case, it does appear to be a bogus error message, hiding the actual issue

Comment: Wow. This helped! I only  had `producer: ssl: key-store-location: and password:` configured in application.yaml. And I was getting out of memory in testing environment. I think somewhere in the error log there was also *Topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms*. Adding `spring.kafka.producer.security.protocol: SSL` helped. Thank you.

Comment: You're spot on! Thank you very much indeed. 
Two years on and this is still happening with **Spring Boot 2.7.2** and **Kafka 2.8**.

Comment: Hi, a bit late, but I am facing the same issue even with SSL enabled! any hint? im setting kafkaheapsize to -Xms3G -Xmx3G which is, I suppose, enough for my case.

Comment: I am also getting the below error when I am attempting to start kafka on my mac ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: same here when playing with kafka tools connecting to an AWS MSK cluster... for me was that kafka-topics.sh was not called with "--command-config client.properties" where security.protocol=SASL_SSL

Answer (score 7):

I found another cause of this issue this morning.  I was seeing this same exception except that I'm not using SSL and my messages are very small.  The issue in my case turned out to be a misconfigured `bootstrap-servers` url.  If you configure that URL to be a server and port that is open but incorrect, you can cause this same exception.  The Kafka folks are aware of the general issue and are tracking it here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-498%3A+Add+client-side+configuration+for+maximum+response+size+to+protect+against+OOM

Comment: Yes, after adding sasl client security protocols using --command-config it got worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, using a **Spring Boot 2.7.8** application leveraging Spring Boot **Kafka auto-configuration** (no configuration in Java code), the problem was caused by the security protocol not being set (apparently the default value is `PLAINTEXT`). Other errors I got together with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` are:

```
Stopping container due to an Error
Error while stopping the container: 
Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-':
```

The solution was to add the following lines to my `application.properties`:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.security.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.producer.security.protocol=SSL
```

My attempt to fix it with just:

```
spring.kafka.security.protocol=SSL
```

did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing the issue could not start my producer and consumer for a given topic. Also deleted all unnecessary log files and topics.Even though that's not related to the issue.

Changing the `kafka-run-class.sh` did not work for me. I changed the below files

> kafka-console-consumer.sh
>
> kafka-console-producer.sh

and stopped getting OOM error. Both consumer and producer worked fine after this.

Increased the size to `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1G"` was 512m earlier.

Comment: Sorry that my answer wasn't more clear. `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` is an environment variable and should be set at the command line or in the service that starts the Kafka job. You should not modify the scripts that are part of the Kafka distribution, as they'll be wiped out when you update Kafka.