# Kafka Connect running out of heap space. Already setting `-Xmx12g`

Tags: apache-kafka, out-of-memory, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

My Kafka Connect sink is running out of heap space. There are other threads like this: [Kafka Connect running out of heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964676/kafka-connect-running-out-of-heap-space)

where the issue is just running with the default memory setting. Previously, raising it to 2g fixed my issue. However, when adding a new sink, the heap error came back. I raised Xmx to 12g, and I still get the error.

In my systemd service file, I have:

```
Environment="KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx12g"
```

I'm still getting the heap errors even with a very high Xmx setting. I also lowered my `flush.size` to 1000, which I thought would help. FYI, this connector is targeting 11 different Kafka topics. Does that impose unique memory demands?

How can I fix or diagnose further?

FYI, this is with Kafka 0.10.2.1 and Confluent Platform 3.2.2. Do more recent versions provide any improvements here?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
at io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3OutputStream.<init>(S3OutputStream.java:67)
at io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage.create(S3Storage.java:197)
at io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroRecordWriterProvider$1.write(AvroRecordWriterProvider.java:67)
at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.writeRecord(TopicPartitionWriter.java:393)
at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.write(TopicPartitionWriter.java:197)
at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.put(S3SinkTask.java:173)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:429)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:250)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2018-03-13 20:31:46,398] ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:450)
[2018-03-13 20:31:46,401] ERROR Task avro-s3-sink-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:141)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:451)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:250)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the memory requirements of the S3 connector depend on the number of outstanding partitions and the `s3.part.size`. Try setting the latter to 5MB (the minimum allowed). The default is 25MB.

Also read here, for a more detailed explanation of sizing suggestions:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/29

Comment: Each topic has three partitions. There are 11 topics, actually 14 if I count other sinks. 14 * 3 * 25MB is about 1GB? 12GB should be plenty

Comment: Depends on the partitioner you are using too. Partitions are the outstanding partitions to S3. There's not necessarily a 1-to-1 mapping with Kafka partitions.

Comment: @clay Did changing this config solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I know nothing about Kafka.

However, as a general rule, when a process meets some kind of capacity limit, and you can't raise that limit, then you must throttle the process somehow.  Suggest you explore the possibility of a periodic pause.  Maybe a sleep for 10 milliseconds very 100 milliseconds.  Something like that.

Another thing you can try is to *pin* your Kafka process to one specific CPU.  This can sometimes have amazingly beneficial effects.

Comment: Adding a periodic pause isn't exactly possible in a vendor provided product without forking it and adding code to do so... Also, Kafka is *streaming messages*, so pausing anything is therefore preventing that "real time" use case

Comment: If you pin the process to a cpu you can pin another one to another cpu, and so on. I did this with a real-time messaging server, once.  Massive improvement just by stopping the thread thrashing. Leave 25% of cpus for the OS.