# Why set Xmx value only then java API get heap init value is 0?

Tags: java

When I set Xmx value,I found heap init value is 0 through Java API,
I set Xms and Xmx values ,I found heap init value is not 0 through Java API,
I not set Xms and Xmx values ,I found heap init value is not 0 through Java API.

1. -Xmx512M
2. -Xms256M -Xmx512M
3. not set

I found that JDK1.5 would have this problem.
    MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage();
    heapMemoryUsage.getInit();

I want to know the principle

Comment: Your question is extremely hard to understand. The English is bad but that's acceptable, however the question seems insensible, assuming that I'm reading it correctly. From what I am gather about the question, the value you are setting via "Xmx"(max heap size) is "0" ,

Comment: @Immortal - could you paste your command line arguments here?

Answer (score 1):

Trying my best to interpret: `-Xms` lets you set the minimum heap size. This is what the JVM starts with. As your process requires more memory, it requests memory from the OS. `-Xmx` lets you set the max heap size; if your process exceeds the value you set for `-Xmx`, it throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Perhaps, this is what you need: [How's the default java heap size determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)?

Comment: "max heap size and, by extension, max memory" just a suggestion, since you mentioned the memory anyway. Will delete this comment if you want.

Comment: I would leave your comment there for posterity: memory in Java is heap and stack, and `-Xmx` doesn't cap stack.

Comment: Could you possibly post a (couple) link(s) in regards to that statement? I'm not calling you a liar, but I'm curious because I could have swore that Xms/Xmx were related to heap/stack depth, as opposed to being directly related to the memory. I would actually enjoy reading up on this tbh, the more you know.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, and I recount the question. Can you understand it? What you are answering now is not what I want

Comment: @Immortal, I personally believe that it may have something to do with the bean. I'll admit that it's fully possible that this is an incorrect statement, though as I can't say for certain. However, at this time, I would like to suggest that you try using functions within `Runtime.getRuntime()` to calculate the available/used/total memory values, to see if the result comes out the same. I use Java version 8/9, I've never used 1.5, even on linux 1.6 was the earliest version I recall working with.