# Memory usage of a program running in two different languages (C#, Java)

Tags: java, c#, memory

I've written a simple program in two different languages, and the result has astonished me!
My application is a simple program (Hello world!).
The C-Sharp program took about 3 MB of RAM, but in Java-FX it was about 78 MB.
Is Java really using that much memory?!
Is there a way to reduce the amount of memory?

Comment: You can't draw any conclusions from that, and you're wasting your time if you're worrying about memory when you're still writing hello worlds.

Comment: All the difference means is jre is optimized differently at startup than .net. This from a C# guy that only does java on occasion. Unless you're writing a hello world program that needs to be highly optimized this is no reason to fret.

Comment: see how much more memory it takes to print "Hello World" again on another line of your java code and if the memory doubles I'd start to worry...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of the java virtual machine, the default initial heap size is a reasonable minimum, varies by platform, and can be set at startup. So yes, you can reduce it.

About changing the size and more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

About the default heap size: [How is the default java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)