# Java heap value of Xms

Tags: tomcat, weblogic

Eg Java 8 on any tomcat, WebLogic application server on RedHat Linux.
I understand that Xms specifies the minimum and Xmx specifies the max. However, when I set Xms to the same value as Xmx, is the OS supposed to allocate the memory slice to the heap at startup ? That does not seem to be the case ; eg, if I set Xms and Xmx to 1GB, the OS does not fully allocate 1gb at startup to the Java process and seems to allocate memory based on usage. What then is the purpose of Xms ?

EDIT : Its not a duplicate of the other question. What I am asking here is the value of Xms and how it impacts the heap.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the default Java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)