# What are the recommended JVM arguments for a Java 11 app on App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-11

Several sources show how JVM arguments such as -Xmx can be set in the app.yaml entryPoint command:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/building-app/writing-web-service
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java11/kotlin-ktor/app.yaml

However I don't see any documentation about the recommended settings or if it is required for good performance.  What settings are used if we do not specify memory values?  Do the memory settings adjust automatically as the machine type changes?

Answer (score 5):

There are no universal "recommended" arguments / settings.  Settings that may be good for one application or use-case can be terrible for another one.

As a general rule, no JVM settings at all is good *starting point*.  Then you observe, measure, tune, repeat until performance is acceptable.  (Or don't bother.)

> What settings are used if we do not specify memory values? Do the memory settings adjust automatically as the machine type changes?

The default heap size values depend on the Java version and the platform.  For recent Oracle / OpenJDK versions, the default max heap size is 1/4 of  physical RAM and the default initial heap size is 1/64th of physical RAM; see

- [How is the default Java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined)
- [GC Ergonomics: Garbage Collector, Heap, and Runtime Compiler Default Selections](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/ergonomics.html#GUID-DA88B6A6-AF89-4423-95A6-BBCBD9FAE781)

You can also use the `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` option to print the values of all JVM settings.