# Is setting JVM Xmx option in Google App Engine Standard useful?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, memory, jvm

I've a simple Spring Boot application running on Google App Engine Standard Java 11 environment F2 instances. However, I occasionally get errors such as:

> Exceeded soft memory limit of 512 MB with 592 MB after servicing 18320
> requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.

Instead of upgrading to a larger instance type, I'd prefer to limit memory usage, even if it degrades performance a bit.

Since an F2 instance has 512MB of available memory, would it help to set JVM's -Xmx option to a value like say, 480MB? Or will it make things worse by converting Google's "Exceeded soft memory limit" warning to a full blown OutOfMemory error?

Thanks

Comment: I have posted the answer,Hope that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the amount of memory the jvm is using, but there are no universal "recommended" arguments / settings. Settings that may be good for one application or use-case can be terrible for another one.As a general rule, no JVM settings at all is a good starting point.

When you face the Exceeded soft private memory limit error you have two alternatives to follow:

- You can upgrade your instance to an another with more [memory](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes)
- You can reduce the chunks of data you process in each request, process the XML file in smaller pieces and keep the smaller instance doing the work.

Here is a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59924856/18265638) post which can help.

Answer (score 0):

A Java process can consume more memory than what is specified via -Xmx. That applies only to max *heap* size.
As such, if you want to limit it, you should specify significantly less than 512 MB.
There are other flags to limit some portions of non-heap memory like `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`.

By default, 1/4th of available RAM is assigned as Xmx.
You should check what are the actual settings your app is running with, perhaps via `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`.

I suggest reading this excellent post by a JVM expert explaining various types of JVM memory: [Java using much more memory than heap size (or size correctly Docker memory limit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438)